# Fade Transitions on Ember

Tags: jquery, ember.js, fade

That's a very direct question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere:
Is there a way to convert all the link-to transitions in an ember site into fade transitions?
Seems to me that is possible, but I couldn't make this right.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, have a look at [ember-animated-outlet](https://github.com/billysbilling/ember-animated-outlet). There's also a [live demo](http://ember-animated-outlet-demo.herokuapp.com/)